# Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_substr()

Tags: magento-1.9, shared-hosting

i get this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_substr() in /home/onyzcmzsiaxm/public_html/purplerooms/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php on line 103

I am using free shared hosting.So i have no support

Comment: Your PHP version might not have iconv support enabled. Can you add a phpinfo to the site? That should tell you if iconv is available or not (seeing as you probably don't have access to the PHP.ini file).

Comment: I have full access of php.ini when i put in public_html. This is the php info: https://www.projectok.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: I couldn't see an iconv enabled entry in the php info. Look in the php.ini file for the line ;extension=iconv.so and remove the ; if the line is commented out.

Comment: Can you please give me php.ini file thats is enabled iconv. Its a shared linux hosting.